# "Prepare invoice" screen based Web API stops working after Acumatica was upgraded from V6 to 2018R2

Tags: web-services, acumatica

We have screen based API to add Sales Order and then prepare invoice, and it used to work well until recently after we upgraded Acumatica from v6 to 2018R2. Based on release note and code, it seems the only difference is the "Quick Process" option, which is only available in 2018R2, however, we didn't turn on that option, and assumed it should not affect our API.

The following the is the API code:

```
            ....................
            SO301000Content SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
            context.SO301000Clear();

            SO301000.Actions.PrepareInvoiceAction.Commit = true;

            List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();

            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = soType, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType});
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = soNbr, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = customerCD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer, Commit = true });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = customerLocation, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Location});


            cmds.Add(SO301000.Actions.PrepareInvoiceAction);
            cmds.Add(SO301000.Actions.Save);


            SO301000Content[] SO30100content = context.SO301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
            .......................
```

After this code runs, we got error like:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> PX.Data.PXActionDisabledException: Error: The Save button is disabled.
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()
at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2)
at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()
at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.Submit(String screenId, IReadOnlyList`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, PXGraph& graph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Boolean mobile, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode, Boolean mobile, PXGraph& forceGraph, String& redirectContainerView, String& redirectScreen, Dictionary`2 viewFilters)
at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Submit(String id, IEnumerable`1 commands, SchemaMode schemaMode)
at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Submit(Command[] commands)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Does anybody have any idea about this issue?

By the way, we are going to move to REST API in the near future but due to the workload, we would like to upgrade first so we have to get this API work first.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there really a need to Save in that context? The error seems to imply Save button is in disabled state as if the document isn't dirty.

Comment: You are right. After I removed the "save", the error disappeared. Many thanks! But whydid it not have problem in v6.1? Just curious.

Comment: The product code have changed since then leading to different behavior. I'm more surprised about the mobile error behavior, I don't recall calling a disabled action lead to any error on the web version.